# Running Docker Creates Vite Issues

Tags: docker, vite

```
web_services-api-1            | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_services-frontend-1       | node:fs:1395
web_services-frontend-1       |   handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
web_services-frontend-1       |   ^
web_services-frontend-1       |
web_services-frontend-1       | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/frontend/node_modules/.vite/deps_temp'
web_services-frontend-1       |     at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1395:3)
web_services-frontend-1       |     at runOptimizeDeps (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:42704:14)
web_services-frontend-1       |     at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:42112:58)
web_services-frontend-1       |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
web_services-frontend-1       |   errno: -13,
web_services-frontend-1       |   syscall: 'mkdir',
web_services-frontend-1       |   code: 'EACCES',
web_services-frontend-1       |   path: '/frontend/node_modules/.vite/deps_temp'
web_services-frontend-1       | }
web_services-frontend-1       |
web_services-frontend-1       | Node.js v18.13.0
```

It has the frontend/node_modules/ folder with the appropriate permissions but it lacks a .vite/deps_temp folder being created.

List of permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 312 arundeep docker    12288 Jan 23 14:24 node_modules

drwxrwxr-x  6 arundeep docker  4096 Jan 22 21:14 vite

drwxrwxr-x 2 arundeep docker   4096 Jan 22 21:14 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arundeep docker   3913 Jan 22 21:14 client.d.ts
drwxrwxr-x 5 arundeep docker   4096 Jan 22 21:14 dist
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arundeep docker    997 Jan 22 21:14 index.cjs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arundeep docker 168938 Jan 22 21:14 LICENSE.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arundeep docker   3980 Jan 22 21:14 package.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arundeep docker   1164 Jan 22 21:14 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 3 arundeep docker   4096 Jan 22 21:14 src
drwxrwxr-x 2 arundeep docker   4096 Jan 22 21:14 types
```

Comment: Why is code trying to write into the `node_modules` directory at run time?  What process set very insecure permissions on that directory?  How are you trying to run the container; do you have some sort of volume mount that hides the image's `node_modules` directory, or tries to persist these changes, or both?

Comment: I'm not sure but in a docker-compose.yml these is a volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
      - /frontend/node_modules . It's some code I'm not sure of.

Comment: That `volumes:` block generally means you're not actually running the code that's in the image; that you're trying to use Docker as a complex and indirect way of running code that only actually lives on your host.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help this problem?